# Bernoulli equation under free fall in inertial frame

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation, free-fall

If a cup of water with a hole on the side of the cup, then there would be water streams out through the hole. And it could be calculated by using Bernoulli's law.
However, if the cup with water and hole now is under free fall, the water would not spill out.

Now I want to explain this situation by using Bernoulli's equation in **inertial frame**.

According to Bernoulli's equation:
$P_1+\rho gy_1+\frac{1}{2}\rho v_1^2=P_2+\rho gy_2+\frac{1}{2}\rho v_2^2$

How could explain it? I think I should establish that $g=0$ in this situation, which is weird.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bernoulli's equation applies to a flow at steady state.  Free fall is not at steady state.  The fluid velocity at a given spatial location is increasing with time.  To describe it with Bernoulli, you need to use a modified unsteady state version of Bernoulli.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's where I am wrong.